# Why does the menu hovering behave different for these items on a list?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

http://jsfiddle.net/z9wAg/

For the music links hovering and aligning works, but not for the pictures! Why? It's the same types, so as I see it, it should work the same way. As you can probably see, though, it doesn't. I've tried to compare them, and they are pretty much the same in the code.

HTML:

```
   <link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div ID="menubox">
        <ul>
        <li><a href="http://folk.ntnu.no/arnstekl/" class="link">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="link">Music</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="https://soundcloud.com/arnsteinkleven/" class="link" target="_blank">My music</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://folk.ntnu.no/arnstekl/gilberto.html" class="link" target="_blank">The Joao Gilberto project</a></li>
           </ul></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.github.com/arnstein" class="link" target="_blank">Github</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="link">Pictures</a>
            <ul>
                 <li><a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/92472314@N03/" class="link" target="_blank">Flickr</a></li>
                 <li><a href="https://plus.google.com/photos/104927400856808784381/albums/" class="link" target="_blank">Google+ albums</a></li>
             </ul></li>

        <li><a href="https://twitter.com/ArnsteinKleven" class="link" target="_blank">Twitter</a></li>


        </ul>

    </div>
    <div ID="circle">
        <p ID="title"> &alpha; <br> &Gamma; <br> &Pi; <br> &zeta; <br> &tau; <br> &xi; <br> &iota; <br> &Pi; </p>
    </div>
    </body>
```

CSS:

```
#menubox
{
    width: 8%;
    height: 30%;
    border: 10% solid #C7D93D;
    border-radius: 5%;
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 12%;
    margin-left: 18%;
    font-family: Ubuntu, Futura, Trebuchet MS;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
}


#menubox ul li a
{
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 200%;
    color: #FFF0A5;
}

#menubox ul li
{
    color: #468966;
    font-family: Ubuntu, Futura, Trebuchet MS;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

#menubox ul
{
    color: #468966;
    font-family: Ubuntu, Futura, Trebuchet MS;
}

#menubox ul ul
{
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
    list-style: none;
}

#menubox ul ul li
{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 40%;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 60%;
    text-align: left;

}

#menubox ul ul a
{
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#menubox ul li:hover a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFB03B;
} 

#menubox ul li:hover ul
{
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    color: #FFB03B;
}

#menubox ul li:hover ul a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF0A5;
}

#menubox ul li:hover ul li a:hover
{
    color: #FFB03B;
}


div p
{
    color: #FFF0A5;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 300px;
    line-height: 60px;
}


#circle
{
    border-radius: 100%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
    -moz-border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: #B64926;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 9%;
    margin-left: 52%;
    text-align: center;
}

#title
{
    text-color: #FFF0A5;
    font-size: 350%;
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
}

body
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #468966;
    font-family: Ubuntu, Futura, Trebuchet MS;
}

.link
{
    text-color: #FFF0A5;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: It's because you have different length text yet you have used percentages. The `li` element is absolutely positioned and the child is relative. If you have the same length text it would be fine eg http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/z9wAg/4/ But because you don't, you will have set set a width in `px` not `%`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By making the menu LIs the same width, it seems to have eliminated this issue for me.

```
#menubox ul li
{
    color: #468966;
    font-family: Ubuntu, Futura, Trebuchet MS;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: relative;
    width:190px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z9wAg/2/

Answer (score 0):

From what I saw, the problem is that in the [`margin-left` CSS rule](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#propdef-margin-left) of `#menubox ul ul li`.
Instead of it being 40% you could specify a concrete distance (e.g. 80px).

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/z9wAg/3/)